# Range variable errors in Excel VBA ; "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba, object, range, runtime-error

I don't know why I keep getting an error when I try to run this code. The error occurs after the `MsgBox` appears but after clicking "debug" on the error box, the `Msgbox` line is highlighted. I suspect there is a problem with the `First` and `Last` range variables.

I tested that the variables ws and Criteria are valid and I commented out the rest of the function to find the problem. I was using this code earlier and had no problem with it so I don't know what changed.

```
Function TotalUniqueValues(ws As Worksheet, Criteria As String) As Integer
    Dim Last As Range, First As Range, rng As Range

    Set Last = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Criteria, _
        After:=Range("B1"), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False)

    Set First = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Criteria, _
        After:=Range("B1"), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)

    MsgBox Last.Address

    Set rng = Range(First, Last)
End Function
```

Comment: It's likely that `Last` or `First` or both failed to find `Criteria` and as a result those variables are actually still `Nothing` instead of being set to a found range.  Typically this is handled by testing if the variable is nothing, like so: `If Last Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Error: Failed to find Last cell"`

Comment: It's possible there's a problem with the Criteria variable. You could try adding a `debug.print Criteria` line into there to see if it'sa good value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely the Last object never got set.
You can test it by putting this line **before** MsgBox Last.Address

```
if Last is Nothing then stop
```